# iPhone - How to access global variable with one class to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new to iPhone devlopment.

I have a iphone app with 2 classes in it..( namely mainView,subView)

In the mainView , i have a global variable named currentId

i set the value for the currentId as 5.

Now what i need to know is how can i access that currentId into the subView class.

Please help guide me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think some part of the answerer here is correct but we need to add something more here..

So I will go step by step

1 Definitely u need to make currentID as the property in MainView as stated by other answerers

2 As for Sudhanshu's answer , If u alloc and init mainview , a new viewcontroller will be initialised and hence its currentID will any value any value, so that is not correct.

3 Now for the solution part:-
There are two solutions for this :-

(1) `mainview* vc = (mainview*)self.parentViewController;`

then access currentID as `vc.currentId`

Dont forget to import "mainview.h" in ur subview

(2) use appdelegate variables i.e. declare currentID in ur appdelegate
and make it as a property

then set currentID in mainview as :-

> urAppDelegate *delegate =
>   (urAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication
>   sharedApplication]delegate];
>   delegate.currentID=@"5";

and access in subview as

> urAppDelegate *delegate =
>   (urAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication
>   sharedApplication]delegate];
>   NSLog(@"%@",delegate.currentID);

Dont forget to import "urAppDelegate.h" in both viewcontrollers

Answer (score 1):

@barbgal ....you can access your variable currentid in the subview.......my making object of the mainView in the you subview class

Lets suppose your currentid variable is of type NSInteger...

mainView.h

```
NSInteger currentID;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger currentID;
```

mainView.m

```
 @synthesize currentID;
    currentID = 5; 
 //as you want to assign 5 to it
```

Now in your subView class made the object of the mainView class

eg:- `mainView *mainView = [[mainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"mainView"bundle:nil];`

Now assign it anywhere in your subView class as `mainView.currentid`......Do what u want to do with this currentid in the subView class

Comment: @barbgal not a problem if u don't have the nib file.....made a simple object....as u made in most of the cases alloc init type.

Answer (score 0):

for accessing currentId you need to make it a property then by making the object of mainView class in subView class you can acces the currentID.

in mainView.h

```
NSInteger currentID;

@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger currentID;
```

in mainView.m

```
@synthesize currentID;
```

and set its value where you want and in subView make object of mainView class and by using . operator you can access this prperty.